# angular2 canReuse in the release candidate router

Tags: angularjs, angular

The angular 2 documentation, and a few articles (such as the angular 2 [cheat sheet](https://angular.io/cheatsheet)) I have found on the internet refers to a `CanReuse` interface and a `routerCanReuse` method in angular2 that informs the router that the component can be re-used when navigating back to it rather than re-created.

This however seems to have been refactored or removed in the release candidate router and I can find no mention of what it has changed to. The [document linked](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WLSNV3V1AKdwLwRiLuN7JqbPBKQ_S5quRlcT5LPIldw/edit#heading=h.5f731upydzuq) to in the angular2 change log referring to the router refactoring seems not to mention the concept of component re-use.

Any ideas how this can be done in angular2 RC, or if this is even possible any more?

Comment: I guees it was not yet implemented but this router will be replaced *again* soon anyway. It's better to stick with `@angular/router-deprecated` for the time being.

Comment: Thanks, i have started using the new-new router now. Angular's definition of a release candidate is somewhat different from mine.

Comment: They don't communicate well what *is* and what *is not* RC. RC only applies to `@angular/core`. The other modules are only currently in the same repo for easier maintenance.